# illegal cyclic reference involving object scala and case class

Tags: scala, scala-2

Why do I get an error saying illegal cyclic reference? I thought objects in scala are like singleton and act as a container and cannot be instantiated. Why it is cyclic? How to fix this error without moving case class `Baz` out of object `Bar`?

```
trait Foo[T]

object Bar extends Foo[Bar.Baz] {
  case class Baz()
}
```

Error:

```
illegal cyclic reference involving object Bar
object Bar extends Foo[Bar.Baz] {
```

Comment: Interestingly, Scala 3 accepts this code. I'm not sure why Scala 2 doesn't.